# Incorrect datetime value while comparing a datetime value with null

Tags: mysql, laravel, datetime, null, query-builder

I have two datetime columns in my database(mysql)- completed_at, due_date. I am using lumen framework which is connected to mysql. The problem is my 'completed_at' columns is nullable and contains null value. Now I need to count how many records have completed their work before their due_date, if their 'completed_at' is not null.

My code is-

```
$completed_tasks_before = Task::where('tasks.assignee_id', $current_user->id)
                                        ->where('status','completed')
                                        ->where('completed_at', '<>', null)
                                        ->where('due_date' ,'>=', 'completed_at')
                                        ->count();
```

I expect this to give me count of records where due_date >= completed_at but it gives me following error-

```
SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1525 Incorrect DATETIME value: 'completed_at' (SQL: select count(*) as aggregate from `tasks` where `tasks`.`assignee_id` = 2 and `status` = completed and `completed_at` is not null and `due_date` >= completed_at)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you compare the `due_date` column to `completed_at` STRING not the value of this column. So change this line:

```
->where('due_date' ,'>=', 'completed_at')
```

to this:

```
->whereColumn('due_date' ,'>=', 'completed_at')
```

See the [documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/queries#where-clauses) (the `whereColumn / orWhereColumn` section)

Comment: Thanks, and I just wasted my 3 hours on Internet just to find this.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `whereNotNull` for `not null` condition.

You should use `whereDate` rather then `where` for date comparison. Please go through https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/queries#where-clauses to know more.

Answer (score 0):

Let me explain a bit.

```
... and `due_date` >= completed_at
                      ^
                      this is not a column, but plain string value
```

This is why you're getting the error.

So, you could go with:

```php
->where('column_name', '>', DB::raw('other_column_name'))
```

or

```php
->whereRaw('column_name > other_column_name')
```

Answer (score 0):

Oh well, turns out I am an idiot. The where clause in Laravel does not compare two columns, rather I am supposed to use whereColumn. Earlier, it was comparing the value of column 'due_date' with the string 'completed_at'. Now my new code is-

```
        $completed_tasks_before = Task::where('assignee_id', $current_user->id)
                                        ->where('status','completed')
                                        ->whereColumn('due_date', '>=', 'completed_at')
                                        ->count();
```